# WordPress. Удаление родительских скриптов и стилей

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал дочернюю тему, она грузит родительские скрипты и стили, которые я вообще не использую, зачем делал ее как дочернюю? не спрашивайте :-)
Не будут ли у меня потом проблемы после удаления всех сторонних скриптов, методом remove_all_filters()?
Спасибо.

Comment: `она грузит родительские скрипты и стили` и `Не будут ли у меня потом проблемы после удаления всех` О_о

Comment: Я там ничего родительского не подключал вручную, видимо как то наследуется, сейчас хочу в файле functions.php(дочерней) применить remove_all_filters()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wp_deregister_script \  wp_deregister_style
```

По `handle` именам родительских скриптов и стилей.

**Обновление**

Найти сперва стили которые, по вашему мнению, ненужны вам в дочерней теме. Поиском по всем файлам найти, где эти скрипты подключаются в родительской теме (искать `wp_enqueue_script\wp_enqueue_style`). Первым параметром будет записан `handle` - имя для конкретного скрипта/стиля. Ну и в дочерней теме в `functions.php` отключать выбранные ненужные файлы.

Comment: Большое спасибо за пояснения!